# Rendering gridstack in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, meteor, rendering

I am using gridstack.js (https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) in Meteor.

I have the grid

```
<template name="grid">
  <div class="grid-stack" data-gs-width="12" data-gs-animate="yes">
    {{#each tiles}}
      {{> gridItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and I apply gridstack to my grid element with

```
Template.grid.onRendered(function() {
  $('.grid-stack').gridstack();
});
```

It works as it should, but if I first go to another route and then back to the route with the grid, the gridstack features are not "active" any longer (but the console doesn't say anything wrong). If I refresh, the gridstack will again work as it should. So the problem occurs only when I come back to this page without refreshing the entire page.

I have tried changing `onRendered` to `onCreated`, and suddently the grid gets the exact same behaviour when I refresh, i.e. the gridstack doesn't work neither when refreshing the page nor when I first go to another page and then back to the page with the grid.

So I guess I should still use `onRendered`, but it seems Meteor doesn't render the same way when I 'browse' between pages. Should I probably deinitialize the library when I leave the page, so it can initialize correctly again when the template is rerendered?

## Edit

I have tried

```
Template.grid.onRendered(function() {
  var $el = $('.grid-stack');

  // destroy if already applied
  if ($el.data('gridstack')) {
    $el.data('gridstack').destroy();
  }

  // apply gridstak to grid element
  var grid = $el.gridstack();
});
```

and also

```
Template.grid.onDestroyed(function() {
  $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack').destroy();
});
```

but neither works.

But it says

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...).destroy is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem while I was implementing Gridstack on AngularJS. The Page change breaks the Gridstack. Here is how I solved the issue in my controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'analyticsService', '$modal', '$timeout', function($scope, analyticsService, $modal, $timeout) {
    $scope.homeWidgets = [
        {sizeX: 6, sizeY: 5, row: 0, col:0, type: 'ndl-action-items'},
        {sizeX: 6, sizeY: 5, row: 0, col:7, type: 'ndl-stage-shift-graph'},
        {sizeX: 6, sizeY: 5, row: 1, col:0, type: 'ndl-nodules-in-system'},
        {sizeX: 6, sizeY: 5, row: 1, col:7, type: 'ndl-case-volume'}
    ];
    $scope.loadGrid = function() {
        if ($scope.homeGrid && $scope.homeGrid.destroy) {
            $scope.homeGrid.destroy();
        }
        var options = {
            cell_height: 70,
            vertical_margin: 10
        };
        // console.log("init grid");
        $scope.homeGrid = $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
        // console.log($scope.homeGrid);
    };
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
        $timeout($scope.loadGrid, 300);
        // event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        // console.log('loaded');
        // $scope.loadGrid();
    });
}]);
```

So basically when my view reloads, I destroy the grid object if it exists and then recreate it. I had to use timeout so that the DOM gets loaded before the grid is initialized.

Comment: I have tried destroying (if already initialized) before initializing. I have edited my question with code